# JAX-RS/Rest: Set a parameter multiple times, or use a single comma-delimited parameter?

Tags: parameters, jax-rs

I read that the HTTP way to pass an array in a request is to set a parameter multiple times:

```
1) GET /users?orderBy=last_name&orderBy=first_name
```

However, I've also seen the comma-delimited parameter (and I feel this is "cleaner"):

```
2) GET /users?orderBy=last_name,first_name
```

I want to implement multi-sorting (ordering users by last_name, then duplicate last_names are ordered by first_name). Code-wise, this is easy (Google's Guava libraries to the rescue), but how should I expose this? Does the first way even preserve the order of the fields (sort by last_name, then by first_name)?

Spring will magically convert a parameter into a String[] array, if it is set multiple times in the request:

```
... @RequestParam("orderBy") String[] orderBy ... becomes ["last_name","first_name"]
```

This leads me to believe the first way is considered best-practice, although I like the second way...

Comment: This depends on who you got your @RequestParam from. It might be specified in the JAX-RS standard, though.

Answer (score 14):

The first method is the preferred, standard way.

You can certainly use the second way, but you will have to implement your own way of tokenizing the request parameter value, with all the issues that involves. For example, consider what happens if one of your values contains a ',' character.

Because the first is quite standard, it has the benefit of fitting in nicely with jax-rs, and validation frameworks; because we always validate our inputs, right? ;)

Comment: The order is critical for OPs requirement but I don't think order is guaranteed by spec. So first method is unreliable and should not be used.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a matter of opinion.  JAX-RS allows you to have parameters like:

```
@QueryParam("orderBy") List<String> orderBy
```

which I think would do the same thing as Spring regarding "magically convert" part.  I don't necessarily think this is indicative of a "best practice" or not.  It's just that some parameters can have multiple values and the frameworks allow you to read those multiple values (think certain HTML forms).

Personally, I would use a single value that's comma delimited.  It's "cleaner" like you said and the value is easier to build (you're not relying on the order of parameter key/values which can lead to some trouble for client developers).

Comment: This approach will returns List with one element "last_name,first_name" in it. Isn't it?

Comment: @Normal I meant that the example List<String> line of code would be  close to what Spring provides. I'm unsure if the JAX-RS spec was clarified to preserve order (and I believe most implementations should now). The comma delimited single value was an alternative approach (and if you combined both the List and the single string that's comma delimited, you will get only one element as you commented on). Looking back, the List<String> approach with "GET /users?orderBy=last_name&orderBy=first_name" is also good and is more of a standard approach in other language frameworks.